# Json.net custom serializer ; ouput without double/simple quote

Tags: c#, json.net

In my custom serializer, I do the following

```
var gridHeader = (GridHeader)value;
var jsonHeaderList = new JArray();

foreach (var columnDefinition in gridHeader.ColumnDefinitionList)
{
    var jsonHeader = new JObject();
    jsonHeader.Add(new JProperty("field", columnDefinition.Name));
    jsonHeader.Add(new JProperty("title", columnDefinition.Text));
    jsonHeaderList.Add(jsonHeader);
}

jsonHeaderList.WriteTo(writer);
```

And here is an example of the output :

```
[ { "field" : "something", "title" : "something" }, { "field" : "something", "title" : "something" } ]
```

The big problem here, is that I need to have this output :

```
[ { field : "something", title : "something" }, { field : "something", title : "something" } ]
```

**Notice the difference? There is no double quote around the field and title.**

Tryed a couple of thing with Json.net to make sure those double quotes werent there, but no positive results so far...

Comment: "I need to have this output" that is not [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: Really? Crap that would explain a lot... so basically, in my javascript, I need to transform that json into a javascript object and it will remove the double quotes?

Comment: JSON.parse would solve it on the javascript side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is a javascript object, which isn't the same as JSON (although pretty close).

If you use `JSON.parse()` on json, you'll get the format you want.

Comment: Yup, just as Mason said in the comments. Thank you Smeegs!

Comment: Ah...looks like me beat me to it.